# Reorganizing an Array of Objects in Javascript: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects, each of which pairs an entry id with a tag id. I'm trying to reorganize this so that I get an object with a single index for each unique `entry_id` with a corresponding list of the associated tags.

**Changing this:**

```
tags_entries = [
          {'entry_id': 1, 'tag_id': 1},
          {'entry_id': 1, 'tag_id': 2},
          {'entry_id': 2, 'tag_id': 1},
          {'entry_id': 2, 'tag_id': 3},
          {'entry_id': 3, 'tag_id': 1}
]
```

**To This:**

```
   entries = {         
         1:
         { 
          'tags': [1, 2]
         },
         2:
         {
          'tags': [1, 3]
         },
         3:
         {
          'tags': [1]
         }
    }
```

The function I have so far is below, but I'm getting this error with it: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`, which is coming from the line after the `else`

```
function collect_tags(tags_entries) {
    out = {};

    for (i=0; i<tags_entries.length;i++) 
    {
        out[tags_entries[i]['entry_id']] = {};

        if (!out.hasOwnProperty(tags_entries[i]['entry_id']))
        {

            out[tags_entries[i]['entry_id']]['tags'] = [];
            out[tags_entries[i]['entry_id']]['tags'] = tags_entries[i]['tag_id'];
        } 
        else 
        {
            out[tags_entries[i]['entry_id']]['tags'].push(tags_entries[i]['tag_id']);
        }
    }

    return out;

}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's causing this? Thanks so much.

Comment: `['tags']` = undefined on the object in else. You aren't copying the entire object into `out[#]`. So in the first line of your loop this happens `out[1] = {}`. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

So on each iteration, you use the line:

```
out[tags_entries[i]['entry_id']] = {};
```

Then you ask, does `out` have a property `tags_entries[i]['entry_id']` ?

Of course it does, you just created it, it's an empty object.

Then you access the `tags` property of this empty object and get `undefined`. Then you try to call the `push` method of undefined and get your error.

As an alternative, if you don't need to support old versions of IE, I would suggest a functional style replacing the entire thing with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) .

Or if you just want to fix your code, maybe:

1. Replace your if condition with `out[tags_entries[i]['entry_id']]['tags']`
2. Replace this weird double assignmenet to the same address

   `out[tags_entries[i]['entry_id']]['tags'] = [];`

   `out[tags_entries[i]['entry_id']]['tags'] = tags_entries[i]['tag_id'];`

with just creating the array

```
out[tags_entries[i]['entry_id']]['tags'] = [];
```

3. Don't have an else. Always push your value onto the array, even if you had to just create it.

Comment: `function combineBy(key){return function reduceToIndex(accum,x,i){if(!accum[x[key]]){accum[x[key]]=[];}accum[x[key]].push(x.tag_id);return accum};} var entries = tags_entries.reduce(combineBy("entry_id"),{})`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want:

```js
tags_entries = [
          {'entry_id': 1, 'tag_id': 1},
          {'entry_id': 1, 'tag_id': 2},
          {'entry_id': 2, 'tag_id': 1},
          {'entry_id': 2, 'tag_id': 3},
          {'entry_id': 3, 'tag_id': 1}
]

entries = {}

tags_entries.forEach(function(e) {
  (entries[e.entry_id] ||
    (entries[e.entry_id] = {tags: []} )).tags.push(e.tag_id);
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(entries));
```